# как рассчитать разницу дат в месяцах

Tags: python, django

файл models

```py
class Dog(models.Model):  
    bdate = models.DateField()
```

файл view

```py
def get_ages(self):
    delta = datetime.now().date() - 
            Dog.objects.values_list("bdate").distinct('bdate')
    return delta
```

В Dog.objects.values_list("bdate").distinct('bdate') лежит quaryset, не могу понять как мне тут время рассчитать.

Comment: `Dog.objects.values_list("bdate").distinct('bdate')` это запрос на получение всех уникальных значений из колонки `bdate`, т.е. вернется список значений, а не одно. Какое значение из списка вы хотите использовать в вычислении?

Comment: я хочу получить их все, но в формате разница месяцев(возраст собаки в месяцах) чтобы можно было по этому значению настроить фильтр

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `annonate`.

```py
qs = qs.annotate(
    old_in_days=Value(localtime(), output_field=models.DateField()) - F('bdate')
)
```

Вычесленное значение будет помещено в `old_in_days` переменную

Подробнее в документации

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/

---

PS: А вообще, если это нужно для фильтра, почему бы не идти от обратного и не фильтровать по датам, который подходят под нужные возраст?

Алгоритм такой:

1. Находим самую старую дату
2. Узнаем даты начала и конца периода относительно текущей
3. Фильтруем по ним (от - до)

Вероятно, этот вариант будет быстрее при больших объемах данных, а может и во всех случаях (или почти)